# UIImageView - Displaying an image from Directory

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview

I have the following code in place:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSString *homeDirectoryPath = NSHomeDirectory();
    NSString *imagePath = [homeDirectoryPath stringByAppendingString:@"/graph.png"];
    NSLog(@"Image: %@", imagePath);

    if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:imagePath isDirectory:NULL]) 
    {
        graph = imagePath;
        //[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:imagePath attributes:nil];
    }
```

'graph' is defined as UIImageView. I'm trying to display the file in the path 'imagePath'. I know the code graph = imagePath is not correct, as the variable 'imagePath' states it contains the path to the image.

How would I display my image located at the specific image path ?

Regards,
Stephen

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'll have to create an imageview object, set it as the image view's image and release the image you created:

```
UIImage *graphImage = [[UIImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile: imagePath];
graph.image = graphImage;
[graphImage release];
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what's the purpose of the initContentsOfFile method ?

Comment: I'm getting errors with initContentsOfFile, but when I use initWithContentsOfFile, it compiles cleanly, but still doesn't display the image.

Comment: sorry.. my bad. it was a typo i meant to type initWithContentsOfFile. i've corrected it in the answer. initWithContentsOfFile should work as long as the image path is correct.

Comment: Thanks Lukya, image is still not displaying as expected, when I display my imagePath in the log file, I get '/Users/stephenconnolly/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/3.1.3/Applications/261904F9-AF97-4C5C-A968-0E51CDD2CD71/Documents/graph.png'. Graph.png exists at this location so I'm not sure whats happening.

Comment: try it on device...  the simulator acts weird sometimes.

Comment: All sorted Lukya, thanks...the last problem was actually with the graph.png file, so I just fixed this and the code above works like a charm.
Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks lukya !! i don't know why i was convert my code to NSURL and made it complex !! anyways, you save my day ! :)